# Binary data of Image as HttpResponse error in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests, httpresponse

I am trying to send the binary data of the image as a HttpResponse for the post request generated by python request lib.
My view function is as follows :

```
def view(request):
    
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    print("type of request:", request.method)
    
    if request.method =="POST":
        
        print( "line 55 EPD, content of POST:", request.body)
        print( "META", request.META)
        print( "FILES", request.FILES)
        print( "headers", request.headers)
        print( "all", request)
        print("Content_params",request.content_params)
        print("COOKIES", request.COOKIES)
        print("accepts", request.accepts("application/octet-stream"))
        print("session:", request.session)
               
      
        with open(r"C:\....\main\image.bin", mode='rb') as p:
            Image=p.read()
            print(type(Image))
            
        return HttpResponse( Image, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'} )
```

and my unit test for generating request is as follows:

```
def make_request():
    import requests
           
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/view/'
    print("before sending the POST")
    print("sending")
    parameters = ( {
        'Size':0,
        'length':1,
    })
    
    
    postresponse = requests.post(url,json=parameters,stream=True, headers= {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'}, timeout=10)
    print(postresponse.status_code)
    print("Now print Response")
    print("headers:", postresponse.headers)
    print("encoding:", postresponse.encoding)
    print("raw:",postresponse.raw)
    print("content:", postresponse.content)

make_request()
```

When my server is running, I receive the successful transfer of the response, but in the unit test code terminal, I receive the error as below:

```
C:...\requests\models.py", line 899, in content
    self._content = b"".join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b""
```

I receive the output until postresponse.raw but unable to output postresponse.content. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

I tried using JsonResponse as return but I get an error message stating byte objects is not serializible.

Answer (score 0):

I think i see where your error comes from.
The HttpResponse object in Django is designed to handle text-based responses. In order to return binary data like your image, you should use the HttpResponse subclass StreamingHttpResponse instead.

You can modify your view function as follows:

```
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse

def view(request):
    
    print("--------------------------------------------")
    print("type of request:", request.method)
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        print("line 55 EPD, content of POST:", request.body)
        print("META", request.META)
        print("FILES", request.FILES)
        print("headers", request.headers)
        print("all", request)
        print("Content_params",request.content_params)
        print("COOKIES", request.COOKIES)
        print("accepts", request.accepts("application/octet-stream"))
        print("session:", request.session)
               
      
        with open(r"C:\....\main\image.bin", mode='rb') as p:
            Image = p.read()
            print(type(Image))
            
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(Image, content_type='application/octet-stream')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="image.bin"'
        return response
```

We set the Content-Disposition header to 'attachment; filename="image.bin"' to tell the browser to download the file rather than display it inline. But as you want.

Tell me if it works for you

Comment: Thank you for the input. I tried using StreamingHttpResponse, The response.content gives me an empty string and in the server part the content is not transferred as before. but some progress to see some changes in the output.

Comment: If you're using StreamingHttpResponse, the response content is not available via the content attribute like it is with HttpResponse. Instead, you'll need to iterate over the response using a loop or some other mechanism to access the content.

For example, in your test code, you can modify the print("content:", postresponse.content) line to read:

for chunk in postresponse.streaming_content:
    print("content:", chunk)